# remove numbers in between document in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have mongo documents with numbers in between. I have to remove those in Notepad++

E.g.

```
/* 1 */
xyzzy
/* 2 */
ABC
/* 3 */
def
```

I have to made them like this:

```
xyzzy
ABC
def
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to remove lines that contain digits in comments?

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^/\*\h*\d+\h*\*/\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
/       # a slash
\*      # an asterisk
\h*     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\d+     # 1 or more digits
\h*     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\*      # an asterisk
/       # a slash
\R      # any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the replace windown:

Check option "Regular expression"

Search for `[0-9]` replace with nothing as you want to delete them